# My raspberry pi 4 didn't boot

Tags: pi-4, boot, boot-issues, bootloader

**My raspberry pi 4 was in normal use yesterday, but didn't boot today:**

I am using the Pi4, suddenly it does not boot into the memory card anymore, only the red light (power light) does not light the memory card reader light (green light). The usb ports also lose the signal.
When i boot OS Raspbian (from this link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/op ... -os-32-bit), my display not signal, all is black.
When I use "Raspberry Pi 4 EEPROM boot recovery" but display is red, not green. I see this link (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentati ... booteeprom)
I checked the GPIO pin and found still 3.3V and 5V, UART still works with random bit characers.
I think I had a problem with my bootloader, because if I don't boot to OS but boot recovery then the SD slot is still working.
I am still a student, throwing away and buying new is a very difficult decision. Please help me. Thank you everyone <3

Comment: The SD Card is probably corrupted. Just restore from your backup.

Comment: `from this link` - not a valid link

Comment: Hi Milliways, how to restore from my backup?

Comment: Hi Jaromanda X, i can't see that link?

Comment: Depends how you backed up. Generally you just use the same installer you used initially. Most backup tools create an image of the installation.

Comment: Hi Milliways, I have backed up from another pi4 (RAM = 4GB). But still cannot boot pi from that backup file. Do I have to find a pi4 with the same RAM configuration?

Comment: Haven't you used an official power supply adapter?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue if the OS is corrupted..

I suggest you to install the OS using Raspberry Pi Imager

The imager formats the SD card for you and writes the OS to it automatically, you can look at [this video](https://youtu.be/ntaXWS8Lk34) from Raspberry Pi which has the step by step process for installing.

You can download it from here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/

---

If re-installing the OS also does not work, it might be a display issue.

For that, remove your SD card and put it in a laptop, after that open the Boot drive (Windows may prompt you to format the card but don't do it).

After that, open the `config.txt` file and add this at the end of the file:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

adding the line `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` forces the rpi to display in HDMI even if no HDMI is detected.

Now your rpi must work :)

---

If that also doesn't work, then the bootloader must be corrupted..

You can refer this page which gives info on downloading the bootloader: https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/blog/2019/10/21/my-raspberry-pi-4-does-not-boot

Comment: I install the OS many times, but don't work for pi

Comment: @NguyenVanTai I have updated the answer, check if this helps in any way :)

Comment: When I use "bootloader" in this link, my green led flashes on off 4 times a cycle. Next, I used an SD card that contained the OS, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have the same issue as this guy here: [Two 'burnt' HDMI ports on two Raspberry Pi 3B+s one after the other](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135267/two-burnt-hdmi-ports-on-two-raspberry-pi-3bs-one-after-the-other)

Burnt out HDMI port because of newest Raspian OS. So you would have a display which does not turn on on the PI.

Check this https://pimylifeup.com/headless-raspberry-pi-setup/ how to setup a headless PI (all done offline on the SD card via laptop) - and then try to boot it and access it via network / ssh / VNC.